# Print large map on Google Maps

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

Is there any way that we can print a large map with all the pins on google maps? EG: there are around 300 pins with places of interest and can we print out a large map (4000 x 6000) PDF and use A0 printer to print the results?

Lets say that the entire UK fits into the A0 page with different pins on the map.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if this helps, but looking at the [Google Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/v3/introduction.html), you could try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function initialize() {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(54,-3);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 9,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
  }

</script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:4000px; height:6000px"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The key thing here is setting the width and height of map_canvas in pixels, so they exceed the size of your browser window. From here on, hopefully it's a question of getting your print settings right to print the whole image.

Comment: I've tested this: it's a hack, but it works ok. As Danniel's answer points out, Google Earth Pro is also an option. To add your pins would need some work with KML in any case.

Comment: Yes, I've tested it too and it works. I also tried it with the Firefox pluging Screengrab (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1146), which is very helpful to export the whole map to an image.

Answer (score 2):

The Google Maps API is not intended for high-resolution printing. On the other hand [Google Earth Pro](http://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/earth_pro.html) boasts high-resolution printing (up to 4,800 horizontal pixels) as one of the main features.

You may want to consider using KML in order to display your markers on both Google Maps and Google Earth. The following articles may help you getting started:

- [Google Maps KML Support](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/mapsSupport.html)
- [KML Tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/kml/documentation/kml_tut.html)
- [Wikipedia: Keyhole Markup Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyhole_Markup_Language)

The following is an example KML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
<Placemark>
  <name>New York City</name>
  <description>New York City</description>
  <Point>
    <coordinates>-74.006393,40.714172,0</coordinates>
  </Point>
</Placemark>
</kml>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://hublog.hubmed.org/archives/001568.html) might help you get started (it draws a big map).

Once you have that, you could use the Google Maps API to draw on the pins.